# How use CompressionStream('gzip') for a file from <input type="file">?

Tags: javascript

I want compress a selected file from `<input type="file">` and download it using native `CompressionStream` (actually work only on Chrome)

```js
async function compress(input) {
  const file = input.files[0];
  const rs = file.stream().pipeThrough(new CompressionStream('gzip'));
  const blob = await new Response(rs).blob();
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open( url );
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="compress(this)">
```

Browser display the binary data instead of download...

Comment: Why do you want to download a file that was selected by the user from their hard drive?

Comment: because the user download the gzipped file..

Comment: Right. In that case you'll want to start a download instead. Create an <a>, link to the url, add a download attribute, then call click() on the <a>.